# Amortized Analysis and Contest Questiosn, there is any problems?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heap, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

I ran into a local contest question as follows.

If on empty `MIN-Heap` we do `n` arbitrary `insert` and `delete` operations, (with given location of delete in min-heap). what is the `amortized analysis` for `insert` and `delete`?

> I) insert O(log n), delete O(1)
>
> II) insert O(log n), delete O(log n)
>
> III) insert O(1), delete O(1)
>
> IV) insert O(1), delete O(log n)

I think this is a problem with this questions, because type of heap is not defined. I read on Google that we have option (1) and (4) for some heap. from expert point of view we can say with this question `can we select all options as True?`

Comment: The type of heap is specified isn't it? It's a min-heap. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap. O(log n) for both operations so the correct answer appears to be (II).

Comment: @Alex min-heap is not the same as `Binary heap`. Min heap defines the behavior and `Binary` / `Fibonacci` / `Binomial` defines implementation. It's true that for `Binary heap` both insert and delete run in `O(log n)` , however, for `Fibonacci` heap times are different ( `O(1)` for insert and `O(log n)` for delete operation). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29 for more details

Comment: @tchrikch I means so all of them is True? because OP use O notation in amortized analysis ?

Comment: @AnjelaDark given the standard heap implementations I) and III) are false since you can't delete in `O(1)` ,  II) and IV) **may** be true and that depends on the implementation. Last but not least option II) is the **worst** case , you can't get below it.

Comment: @tchrikch you are wrong, please study http://cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo09/assignments/assign5sol.pdf delete in O(1) ?!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @AnjelaDark i didn't say it's possible to delete in `O(1)`...

Comment: so (1) and (4) is true ? @tchrikch

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - the question is not correct. Min heap is an abstract data structure that supports operations push and popMin and it may be implemented in many different ways. Depending on the implementation the complexity of the operations will be different. Also delete in a given location is not a class min heap operation. Unless there was more context in the question it is not well defined.

Comment: We sure (1) and (4) is true so other option is subset of these option ? am i right ?

Comment: @AnjelaDark actually none of these answers is guaranteed to be true. Imagine that you decide to implement a min heap in an array and implement popMin by searching linearly for minimal element before deleting it. This would make delete linear. Alternatively imagine that on each insert you sort the array giving `O(log(n) * n )` for instert. It is truth that some of the answers are subsets of others thus if one of the answers is true the other one will be too.  In fact using this logic the answer will not be 1, 3 or 4 because all of them are subsets of answer 2. Still the question is not correct

Comment: but I think O(1) O(1) for insert delete is wrong  :) okey.